# iommu_group directories not found

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I am following this [manual](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3lno0t/gpu_passthrough_revisited_an_updated_guide_on_how/) to passthrough PCI to a guest machine. The problem is that the expected `iommu_group` directories are missing from the respective bus directory. Here's what I've done

- Double checked my BIOS settings and enabled `Virtualization Technology`
- Checked that my `i5 6600k` supports both `VT-x` and `VT-d` technologies
- Passed `intel_iommu=on` to my `systemd-boot` options. `options ... intel_iommu=on`
- Checked kernel ring messages with `dmesg | grep IOMMU` and the only output I get is `[0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled`
- `lspci` recognizes my `GTX 950` card
- Searched the whole root `find / ..` directory for `iommu_groups`. Nothing.

Sadly, when I `ls` the content of `/sys/bus/pci/devices/MY_BUS/iommu_groups` the directory is not there which indicates that my `IOMMU` is not set up properly.